# Suggest hierarchical data structure with nested keys?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Can anyone suggest hierarchical data structure like `tree`, where each vertex key not number, but string or hash of  string. And in each vertex stored info about total amount of vertex children.

Something like this

```
A : {
    amount : 10,
    child1 : { 
        amount : 5
    },
    child2 : {
        amount : 5,
        child3 : {
            amount : 3

        },
        child4 : {
            amount : 2
        }
    }
}
```

I search algorithm to calculate sum of children amount in vertex.

Comment: Is your question that you want an algorithm, or you need a functioning solution to compute the sum?

Comment: I thought you already described it? a tree that each node stored the total amount of its children. what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this: one defers the cost of calculating `amount` so that reading the `amount` is expensive, and the other keeps all `amounts` up-to-date so that updating an `amount` is expensive

---

The first solution:

```
abstract class Node {
  protected List<Node> children;

  public string getKey();

  public int getAmount();
}

class ParentNode {
  // recursively sum the childrens' amounts
  public int getAmount() {
    return children.sum(x => x.getAmount());
  }
}

class LeafNode {
  private int amount;

  public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }

  public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }
}
```

---

The second solution:

```
class Node {
  protected int amount;

  protected Node parent;

  public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }

  // increment the amount, then increment the parent's amount
  public void incAmount(int inc) {
    amount += inc;
    if(parent != null)
      parent.incAmount(inc);
  }

  public string getKey();
}

class LeafNode extends Node {
  // eagerly update the parents' amounts
  public void setAmount(int amount) {
    int inc = amount - this.amount;
    this.amount = amount;
    if(parent != null) parent.incAmount(inc);
  }
}
```